# Problema con redireccionamientos root

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

Veréis, tengo un dominio llamado `www.cssblog.es`, y un subdominio llamado `comunidad.cssblog.es`.

El caso es que al ingresar a `comunidad.cssblog.es` me redirecciona a la página principal. Sin embargo, si escribía `cssblog.es/comunidad/` (la dirección a la que apuntaba el subdominio), si accedía, pero claro yo quiero acceder desde el subdominio.

He probado a meter esto en el htaccess:

```
# Si se accede desde
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} comunidad.cssblog.es
# Y la carpeta solicitada no es "comunidad"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !comunidad/
# accedemos directamente a la carpeta mi/la_url_indicada
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ comunidad/$1 [L]
```

Y ahora al escribir el subdominio no redirecciona sino que sale la pantalla en blanco y se puede leer page not found.

Sin embargo, si accedemos por `comunidad.cssblog.es/index.php` sí conecta a la página (es un foro en vbulletin) y desde allí ya no sale ningún error más.

El fallo es que desde `comunidad.cssblog.es` no entra porque sale page not found, y hay que añadir el index.php

¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar del todo?

Answer (score 0):

Parece ser que tu problema no es con el htaccess, que no debería por que es un subdominio, mas bien con las urls configuradas en tu foro, no se exactamente como se configura el foro que estás utilizando pero en Wordpress cuando cambias de dominio, en tu caso queres cambiar de **cssblog.es/comunidad** a **comunidad.cssblog.es** tenes que configurar la url en la base de datos, hacer reemplazo de url de la antigua por la nueva.

Y también verificar que si tu foro en la carpeta /comunidad tiene un .htaccess para las url amigables este bien configurado, si tiene un htacces con la linea:

```
RewriteBase /comunidad/

#debe quedar así 
RewriteBase /
```

Espero te sirva.